# regex to find sentences not terminated by a period

Tags: regex, perl

In a book ms., I have figure captions that take one of the following forms:

```
cap=['"]Figure caption['"]  (with matching ' or ")
\caption{Figure caption}    (a LaTeX caption)
```

where the style calls for all captions to be terminated by a `.`, i.e.,

```
\caption{Figure caption.}
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't consistent when writing, so only some captions obey the style, and I have ~300 figures in a file tree of ~100 files, so I'd like to find a perl solution for finding the problem cases and making corrections rather than editing manually.

Can someone help?

Let me try to make this more precise with some test cases from my files.  For the `\caption{}` problem, here are a few example lines from my files.  The first three are properly terminated with a `.`.  The rest need a `.` appended before the caption-closing `}`.  Note there can be several sentences in a caption, and other LaTeX material on the same line.

```
\caption{CA plot and mosaic display for the TV viewing data. The days of the week in the mosaic plot were permuted according to their order in the CA solution.}
\caption{Stacking approach for a three-way table. Two of the table variables are combined interactively to form the rows of a two-way table.}\label{fig:stacking}
\caption{Overview of fitting and graphing for model-based methods in \R.}
\caption{Each way of stacking a three-way table corresponds to a loglinear model}\label{tab:stacking}
\caption{CA biplot of the suicide data, showing calibrated axes for the suicide methods}
\caption{Arthritis treatment data, for the relationship of the binary response ``Better'' to Age}
\caption{Space shuttle data, with fitted logistic regression model}
\caption{Observed (points) and fitted (lines) log odds of admissions in the logit models for \data{UCB}}
```

Comment: Have you started working on this and run into a specific problem? If so, please share the code you have already written.

Answer (score 0):

`(\\caption{[^}]*[^\.]}|cap=(['"]).+[^\.]\2)`

https://regex101.com/r/kW9yZ3/2

This one works for the cases you provided for the `\caption{}` format, and some examples I mades for the `cap="..."` format.